# How to avoid voltage spikes from solenoid valves?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage-measurement, surge-protection, transient-suppression, spike

I want to control a solenoid valve (24VDC, ~10W) using an ESP32 MCU. My initial approach to do this was to use a GPIO pin to control a transistor, which again should control a coil relay. This coil relay controls the solenoid valve. The circuit I used for this can be seen below in the schematics for "Relay 1".
[image: Figure 1]

When no load is connected to the relay there is no problem, but as soon as I connect the solenoid to J3, huge voltage spikes appear at all the voltage buses for the ESP32 board.
The voltage spikes can be seen in figure 2.
[image: Figure 2]

My thought so far is that the solenoid valve is of course an inductive load, and the energy stored when it is shut off needs to go somewhere. So my question is, how can I design a protection circuit in order to avoid these large voltage spikes on my voltage bus? I have seen many vague posts about this topic, but I have not yet found a good post explaining this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a diode across J3 -- just like the diode D2 across the relay coil.

Comment: Should probably have mentioned that in the original post, but I have tried that. I put a 1N4001 diode across J3, but then the solenoid valve were always drawing current, even though the relay connection was open, which is really weird.

Comment: Put the diode in the other orientation.

Comment: I would also suggest a snubber circuit across your relay's contacts.

Comment: @jp314: so it is supposed to go from positive to negative voltage?

Comment: Water solenoid valves are commonly 24Vac, so adding the diode would give the symptoms you observed. The simplest solution would be a varistor, say around 14mm with a voltage of over 24Vac. Something like a S14K40. This can be placed across the solenoid or the relay contacts.

Comment: @Kartman hmm that is interesting. All of the solenoids I have tested say 24VDC on them. But I will give it a try, thanks.

Comment: @Marcus Eide - But in your case, it's not what the solenoid requires, but rather what is it being driven from.  Your schematic implies 24 VDC, at least that's way I and others have read it.  If it's really being driven by DC, then a properly oriented diode across J3 should work.

Comment: @SteveSh Yeah the circuit is 24VDC. To avoid any further confusion, when you say properly oriented diode, what orientation is that? My intuition is that it should have the same orientation as the diode in the relay. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Marcus Eide - Yes.  You don't want it to conduct when the 24 VDC is applied to the solenoid.  You want it to conduct when the solenoid de-energizes to provide a closed path for the current that's stored in the solenoid to flow.

Comment: Makes sense, let me try that.

Comment: As many have suggested here, a diode across J3 solved the problem. The reason why it was not working before, was that the diode I used was broken (I guess I put it the wrong way at first and probably blew it). When I swapped it for a new one it worked at first try. Though, I still see some smaller spikes sometimes, but I will give the snubber circuit a try to solve that part. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Made a few PCB's using the new circuit with diode across J3. I also added three ceramic capacitors in parallel to dampen the spikes even more. While testing, these ceramic capacitors die after a while, and there is a short circuit on the 24V. I guess they are dying because of the high voltage spikes? Is there any way around that, or do I just have to remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have the actual circuit some possible solutions would be to use a mercury wetted relay or a solid state device such as a MOSFET to replace the relay contacts. These devices do not bounce like a relay contact does. Without the bounce there will be a nice reduction in both radiated and conducted electrical noise. Each time the contact bounces the solenoid (inductor) is charged then when it opens flyback occurs. **Since the solenoid is inductive flyback protection needs to be somewhere and it is connected with an 'antenna' (wires).** If you do not clamp it, expect it to rise hundreds of volts until something breaks down and consumes the energy. Shielding the wiring from the logic goes a long way is eliminating noise. I am assuming you have a very robust grounding system and no antennas (jumper wires etc) in the area. The lower voltage logic is more susceptible to electrical noise.

Comment: This is a bad idea. The problem is not the contact bounce, but the inductive spike from opening them. A mercury relay would open even sharper and likely generate a larger spike. If the supply is AC (not DC), then a MOSFET wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a relay snubber circuit.

Inductors like the current to stay the same and will provide a voltage to try and balance out any change to the electrical current. This means that when you cut the voltage supply to the inductor, it will supply its own voltage, but the polarity will swap as it becomes a source of EMF. In some situations this can also lead to electrical arcing.

For small DC relays, the standard solution is a flyback diode - put in an antiparallel diode - you can also put in a resistor so that you can control the current and power dissipation across the diode.

When the supply voltage goes from something to nothing and the corresponding supply current also goes from something to nothing, the voltage the inductor supplies can be very, very large - multiples of the original voltage. If you have already built this circuit then you might want to consider if anything connected to you relay has already been damaged by the voltage spike.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode
[https://electric-shocks.com/rl-circuit-analysis/#:~:text=Inductor%20discharging%20Phase%20in%20RL%20circuit%3A&text=The%20energy%20stored%20will%20be,the%20voltage%20across%20the%20inductor](https://electric-shocks.com/rl-circuit-analysis/#:%7E:text=Inductor%20discharging%20Phase%20in%20RL%20circuit%3A&text=The%20energy%20stored%20will%20be,the%20voltage%20across%20the%20inductor).

Comment: Thanks. I will try the things you have mentioned. The circuit is only for testing the current revision. When I figure out a solution to this problem I will order a new revision of PCB and parts.